# Cordova/Phonegap backbutton handler not working

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, back-button

I am using Phonegap and jQuery Mobile. This is my code:

```js
function onDeviceReady() {
  // Register the event listener
  document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
  setPage();
}
function setPage(){
  //All pages at least 100% of viewport height
  var viewPortHeight = $(window).height();
  //alert(viewPortHeight );
  var headerHeight = $('div[data-role="header"]').height();
  var footerHeight = $('div[data-role="footer"]').height();
  var contentHeight = viewPortHeight - headerHeight - footerHeight-120;
  // Set all pages with class="page-content" to be at least contentHeight
  $('div[class="page-content"]').css({'min-height': contentHeight + 'px'});
}
function confirmExit(){
  alert("exit...");
}
// Call onDeviceReady when Cordova is loaded.
// At this point, the document has loaded but cordova-2.2.0.js has not.
// When Cordova is loaded and talking with the native device,
// it will call the event `deviceready`.
//
function onLoad() { alert("onload");
  document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}
// Handle the back button
function onBackKeyDown() {
  alert("onbackkeydown");
  console.log("back clicked");
  confirmExit();
}
$(document).ready(function(){});
```

And in the body tag:

```html
<body onload="onLoad();">
```

But when I load the app I only get the alert in the `onLoad` method.

What I am doing wrong?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I have the exact same organization and it's working for me, but I don't use jQuery Mobile. Have you tried removing jQuery Mobile to check if it that might be causing the problem?

Comment: Did you manage to find out what the problem was? I seem to be having the same troubles and am not using jQuery Mobile.